# Check get_post value after wp-admin login

Tags: customization, wp-admin, hooks, login, actions

I want to check get_option value after login to wp-admin.

I have save the date in get_option. I want to check if value in get_option is same as current date after wp-admin login.

if same then i want to show admin notice.

Everytime when i  logged in to wp-admin it checks the get_option  value.

Here is my code for admin notice. **I have no idea how can i check the get_option value after wp-admin login.**

```
function sample_admin_notice__success() {
            ?>
     <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
     <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
      </div>
     <?php
   }
   add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You keep saying `get_option`, so you know that function exists. Have you even tried just `if ( get_option( 'option_name' ) ) {`?

Comment: Yes,  i know this but i have no idea how can i check after login to wordpress admin?

Comment: What do you mean, just add it to the code you've got there. What does logging in the admin have to do with it?

Comment: I want to check the value of get_option after wordpress admin login.  After login get_option value will be checked.  if current date and value in get_option will be matched then it will show notice.  I can check without admin login but i want to check this only after login to wordpress admin login.

Comment: admin_notices are only going to appear after login, so just add the if statement around the code you've already got.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Can you post the answer i am not getting your comment.   So that i can understand what  you are referring please.

Comment: What format did you save the date in, and what is the name of your option?

Comment: get_option('expiry_date',false)  and i am saving it in  mm/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use a normal if statement around the notice so that it only appears if the value of your option matches the current date.

```
function wpse_277689_admin_notice() {
    if ( get_option( 'expiry_date' ) === date( 'd/m/Y') ) :
        ?>

        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php _e( 'Done!', 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </div>

        <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse_277689_admin_notice' );
```

Comment: I never thought it can be done this way as well. Thanks for your answer.  appreciate your help.